# Should I do full body if I'm working out over 3 years?

Tags: muscle-gain

Can I build more muscles if I'm gonna do full body instead of split(which is, I heard, for athletes who use steroids)? And I hears that we need only 24-72 hours to fully recover and supercompensate. And how much times per week should I work out?

Some facts about me for better understanding

I'm working out over 3 years.

Height 6ft
Weight 205 lbs

Currently I'm using nitrobolon and hmb 3 times a day

Bench press 132lbs yep I'm suck at press
Reverse grip bent over row 220lbs 8 reps
Leg press 660lbs 10-12 reps
Barbell Curl 100lbs 8reps
Military press 66lbs 8 reps

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the next 3 years I'd imagine you'd do a lot of different programs. Why stick to one for all 3 years?

Comment: It worked fine. But lately I've heard about full body and now I'm thinking if I could do it for better muscle growth

Comment: There are a lot of people using split training out there and natural, just saying...

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should look at the total volume done per week. You can structure it however you want based on your time available and training implements.

The workout is just part of an equation for muscle growth. Nutrition and recovery both play a major role too.

You can switch your routine to keep yourself excited and motivated. You can also play with the tempo of your lifts.

Hope these helps a little